# Why is Tensorboard unable to distinguish two different output files in the same directory?

Tags: tensorboard

I have two tf.events files being written into the same directory. When I open tensorboard I don't see these two different files. All I see is a single "." selection under "Runs" when I am trying to view my loss plot, and this loss plot appears to have the two files superimposed on each other.

Is there anyway to change this setting?